# How to fix 403 response when using HttpURLConnection in Selenium since the links are opening manually without any issue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, httpresponse, httpconnection

I was checking the active links in a website with selenium web driver and java. I have passed the links to the array and while verifying I am getting the response as 403 forbidden for all links in the site. It is just a public website anyone can access. The links are working properly when clicking manually. I wanted to know Why it is not showing 200 and what can be done on this situation.

This is for Selenium webdriver with Java

```
for(int j=0;j< activelinks.size();j++) {
        System.out.println("Active Link address and status >>> " +  activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href"));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")).openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        String response = connection.getResponseMessage();
        int responsecode = connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.disconnect();
        System.out.println(activelinks.get(j).getAttribute("href")+ ">>"+ response+ " " + responsecode);}
```

I expect the response code as 200, but the actual output is 403

Comment: This may help https://github.com/mwinteringham/selenium-to-restassured

Answer (score 1):

I believe your need to add the relevant [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) to the HTTPUrlConnection, or even better consider switching to [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) library which is under the hood of [Selenium Java Client](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#java)

So you basically need to fetch the cookies from the browser using [driver.manage.getCookies() function](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) and generate a proper [Cookie request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) for the subsequent calls.

Example code:

```
driver.manage().getCookies()
        .forEach(cookie -> cookieBuilder
                .append(cookie.getName())
                .append("=")
                .append(cookie.getValue())
                .append(";"));

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();

for (WebElement activelink : activelinks) {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(activelink.getAttribute("href"))
            .addHeader("Cookie", cookieBuilder.toString())
            .build();
    Response urlResponse = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String response = urlResponse.message();
    int responsecode = urlResponse.code();
    System.out.println(activelink.getAttribute("href") + ">>" + response + " " + responsecode);
}
```

If you need nothing else but response code you can consider using [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) method to avoid executing calls for the full URLs - this will allow you to save traffic and your test will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

### 403 Forbidden

The HTTP [**`403 Forbidden`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

This status is similar to [**`401`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

---

### Reason

I don't see any such issue in your code block. However, there is a possibility that the *WebDriver* controlled *Browser Client* is getting detected and hence the subsequent requests are getting **blocked** and there can be numerous factors as follows:

- `User agent`
- `Plugins`
- `Languages`
- `WebGL`
- `Browser features`
- `Missing image`

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [How does recaptcha 3 know I'm using selenium/chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835)
- [Selenium and non-headless browser keeps asking for Captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123142/selenium-and-non-headless-browser-keeps-asking-for-captcha/56136820#56136820)

---

### Solution

A generic solution will be to use a **proxy** or **rotating proxies** from the [Free Proxy List](https://sslproxies.org/).

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Change proxy in chromedriver for scraping purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406466/change-proxy-in-chromedriver-for-scraping-purposes/56515662#56515662)

---

### Outro

You can a couple relevant discussions in:

- [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests) and 404 (Not Found) with ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979980/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-429-too-many-req/55986553#55986553)

Comment: Is there any solution for handling this situation

Comment: Updated the answer. let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, **user agent** was the issue in my case (read more here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/05/how-to-handle-http-403-forbidden-error-in-java.html).

Also check what request methods are allowed on your website, you can do that by looking at any endpoint in "Network" tab in Chrome. It should list the allowed request methods, in my case I couldn't use "HEAD", but "GET" did the trick.

Code:

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
boolean brokenLink = false;
    for (WebElement link : links) {
        String url = link.getAttribute("href");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36");

        conn.connect();
        int httpCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (httpCode >= 400) {
            System.out.println("BROKEN LINK: " + url + " " + httpCode);
            brokenLink = true;
            Assert.assertFalse(brokenLink);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Working link: " + url + " " + httpCode);
        }
    }
```