# Java Selenium Run ChromeDriver like a manually human

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been working with Selenium and ChromeDriver. There is a page, which apparently detects that it is a scraper and responds to the URLs with 403 Forbbiden, to solve this I used the following to "Deactivate" the WebDriver's marks.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
this.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

With this it worked well, since apparently he no longer detected the scraper. The problem is that a couple of weeks ago Chrome was updated to its 80 version and this stopped working. Although I have this configuration, it seems that the page detected the scraper again.

I know it's something with the page and the scraper, because if I run it manually it works without problems and it doesn't give me 403 Forbbiden.

URL to scrape = https://www.fedex.com/en-us/home.html

Using manually or ChromeDriver version before v79

[image: Using manually or ChromeDriver version before v79]

Using ChromeDriver after v79

[image: Using ChromeDriver after v79]

I'm using

Java 1.8

Selenium v4.0.0-alpha-3

Chrome v80

ChromeDriver v80

Regards

Comment: Please, share with us the page and what are you trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added it, but the problem is that the page is with username and password. But I left an example of the error.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668773/how-to-fix-403-response-when-using-httpurlconnection-in-selenium-since-the-links/56670134#56670134) helps you?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, because manually if it works for me