# Repetitive Login Ban Issue (Selenium C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am testing a complicated website and have to login every single time I want to test the required features. I got banned by the website last night and had to wait till the morning to work again. Do you have any suggestion for me that I can import some of the website and run it on local server so that I can complete the work without being banned.

Thank you

Comment: save all the cookies and all the http headers, and send them again the next time you use your Selenium Client. Then you also wont get logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if you can *export some of the website and run it on local server*, but there are a couple of alternatives as follows:

- You can use [tor](/questions/tagged/tor) as a *Browser Client* and you can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

  - [How to connect to Tor browser using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783)
  - [How to use Tor with Chrome browser through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689701/how-to-use-tor-with-chrome-browser-through-selenium/55702188#55702188)
- You can use make use the rotating proxies marked with in the **Last Checked** column which gets updated within the [Free Proxy List](https://sslproxies.org/). You can find a couple of related discussions in:

  - [Change proxy in chromedriver for scraping purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406466/change-proxy-in-chromedriver-for-scraping-purposes/56515662#56515662)